# how to prevent div from being stretched

Tags: css, html

here is the code

```
     <div style="display:inline-block; 
                 float:right; 
                 padding:0pt 6pt 4pt 6pt; 
                 margin-left:8pt; margin-top:2pt; margin-bottom:4pt; 
                 border-right:1px dotted black; 
                 border-left:1px dotted black;                 
                 background: url(http://zin.webd.pl/16mm/images/im-bg.png) no-repeat;">

                 <img src="http://zin.webd.pl/16mm/images/midsize/Battersea_Power_Station_-_geograph.org.uk_-_829933.jpg"/>
                 <br/>
                 <span class="caption">Battersea is an area of the London Borough of Wandsworth, England
                 </span>
        </div>
```

div size is just matching the size of the image inside it. image size can be different each time. so the width of div cannot be hardcoded.

the problem is, the caption text stretches my div, so div gets wider than image. how to prevent it ?

Comment: as you are using inline styles, you can use either a server-side language like php or javascript (jquery) to calculate the image size and set the div width/height accordingly

Comment: can span element inherit its width from parent div ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you like a JS trick? If so you can something like this.
Within `<head>` tags define a JS variable. This is to hold the final width of your `div`.

```
<head>
  <script>
    var divWidth;
  </script>
</head>
```

Now add following part. Note that "myDiv" is the id of your `div`.

```
<body>
  <div style="display:inline-block;
             float:right; 
             padding:0pt 6pt 4pt 6pt; 
             margin-left:8pt; margin-top:2pt; margin-bottom:4pt; 
             border-right:1px dotted black; 
             border-left:1px dotted black;                 
             background: url(http://zin.webd.pl/16mm/images/im-bg.png) no-repeat;"
     id="myDiv">
   <img src="http://zin.webd.pl/16mm/images/midsize/Battersea_Power_Station_-_geograph.org.uk_-_829933.jpg"/>
   <br/>
   <script>
      divWidth = document.getElementById('myDiv').clientWidth;
   </script>
   <span class="caption">Battersea is an area of the London Borough of Wandsworth, England
   </span>
  </div>            
  <script>
    document.getElementById('myDiv').style.width = divWidth;
  </script>
</body>
```

What you have done here is get the width of the `div` before the `span` is rendered and then set that width as the width of the `div` after the `span` is rendered.